# Why can't I replace `scanl` with `scanr`?

Tags: haskell

When I call the `scanl` function in Haskell like this it works fine:

```
ghci> scanl (flip(:))[] [3,2,1]
[[],[3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

But if I try to do the same but using the `scanr` function I get this error:

```
ghci> scanr (flip(:))[] [3,2,1]
<interactive>:129:8: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
      Expected: [[a]] -> [a] -> [a]
        Actual: [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
    • In the first argument of ‘scanr’, namely ‘(flip (:))’      
      In the expression: scanr (flip (:)) [] [3, 2, 1]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = scanr (flip (:)) [] [3, 2, 1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:129:1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

What would I have to change to be able to use the `scanr` function with the same parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter in the `scanl` and `scanr` functions are swapped, indeed:

```
scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
```

This makes sense since for `scanl f z [x1, x2, …, xn]` it will produce:

```
[z, f z x1, f (f z x1) x2), …, f (f (… (f z x1) …) xn-1) xn)]
```

whereas for `scanr`, this gives us:

```
[f x1 (f x2 (…(f xn z)…)), …, f xn-1 (f xn z), f xn z, z]
```

The order thus makes it more clear how it will "fold".

You thus run this with:

```
scanr (:) [] [1,2,3,4]
```

which produces:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4],[]]
```

scanr takes thus as first parameter the element of the list, and as second the thus far generated accumulated value.